# xlrd no attribute sheet_by_name

Tags: python, attributeerror, xlrd

When I use xlrd.book.Book.sheet_by_name(), replacing "Book" with the notebook variable name, there is an attribute error stating that module 'xlrd.book' has no attribute "Book". I have checked that the Book object is created with xlrd instead of xlwt.

```
def read_ws(wb, worksheet_name): 
    '''
    Opens a read_only copy of the worksheet.
    '''
    return xlrd.book.wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)

def existing_start_sheet(path, ws_name, data):
    '''
    Reads and modifies and existing starter sheet.
    '''
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook(path)
    workbook_r = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    r_ws = read_ws(workbook_r, ws_name)
    mod_start_sheet(workbook, r_ws, data)
    return
```

Here's the documentation I referred to:
https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=sheet_by_name#xlrd.book.Book.sheet_by_name

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)`? `sheet_by_name` is a method of the `wb` object. I suggest you revisit the tutorials on OOP.

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be return `wb.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)`?

`sheet_by_name` is a method of the `wb` object.

I suggest you revisit the tutorials on OOP.